# What is a good IRC channel for Objective-C and Cocoa programming

Tags: objective-c, irc

What is a good IRC channel for Objective-C and Cocoa programming?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There're #objc and #macdev on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: Why are they retired? Dont chat stay silent like a dead room? If you ask something there is like nobody to do even echo test on those rooms?

Answer (score 24):

For iOS: #iOSdev, #iphonedev, #ipaddev

Comment: irc.freenode.net

Comment: #ipaddev is obsoleted and #iphonedev should be used instead.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Seems like the name should change to `#iosdev` or something now that watches are about to join the party too.

Answer (score 2):

#iphonedev, #objc, #cocoa-init, #swift-lang, #ioswatchdev, #iosdev

All on freenode.net. Some of these channels require you to [register with nickserv](https://freenode.net/faq.shtml%20register%20with%20nickserv.).